# Encoded password does not look like BCrypt when using Spring Security UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, userdetailsservice

When i am using Spring Security UserDetailsService i am encounter Encoded password does not look like BCrypt, whereas without it working fine

Otherwise its working fine

database is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZEo5.png)

From EmployeeServiceImpl

```
 @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByUserName(username);
        System.out.println(employee);
        if (username == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user name or password");
        }
         return new User(employee.getUserName(),employee.getPassword(),
                mapRolesToAuthorities(employee.getRoles()));
}
   private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapRolesToAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(
                        role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

For registration i am using BCryptPasswordEncoder

```
@Override
    public void save(ErmUser ermUser) {

        Employee employee = new Employee();

        // assign user details to the user object
        employee.setUserName(ermUser.getUserName());
        employee.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(ermUser.getPassword()));
        employee.setFirstName(ermUser.getFirstName());
        employee.setLastName(ermUser.getLastName());
        employee.setEmail(ermUser.getEmail());

        // give user role of "EMPLOYEE"
        employee.setRoles(Arrays.asList(roleRepository.findRoleByName("ROLE_EMPLOYEE")));

        // save the user in database
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
```

https://github.com/TilmeezUrRehmanBhatti/thymeleafdemo-employees-db/issues/2

I don't think it's because of the password its somewhere in the code where we are not handling incoming passwords from the user to BCrypt and then matching, while debugging I noticed it try to match with the plain password with is entered by me(user) with BCrypt password from Database. And i don't know how to handle this or convert the input password to BCrypt  because normally it's handled by spring security (If I am not wrong)

Comment: encoded password look like this @luk2302 $2a$04$eFytJDGtjbThXa80FyOOBuFdK2IwjyWefYkMpiBEFlpBwDH.5PM0K,i am using BCryptPasswordEncoder to store data

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description - that is how bcrypt output is supposed to look.

Comment: @TilmeezUrRehmanBhatti Add a breakpoint at this line: `return new User(employee.getUserName(),employee.getPassword(), mapRolesToAuthorities(employee.getRoles()));` and check the value of `employee.getPassword()`.

Comment: @dur , `employee.getPassword()` i am getting $2a$10$egm4nKzQ87RXZho4KTz2hOA.n5o.cwy/WODNp7oGf3It4CvR13jCS but what i notice it matches plan text with bcrypt password from database and that i am not understanding why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is related to column size. As I am using `PostgreSQL`, it might be of type issue.

- [Spring Security : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt](https://mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-encoded-password-does-not-look-like-bcrypt/)

Alter the password column type from `char` to `varchar`, it solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you got that impression. Bcrypt encoder uses Strenth parameter with value from 4 to 31 to encode the text. When it's 4, you will see hashed value something like $2a$04 and when it's 10 (default value) hash will be of pattern $2a$10 
 now, the question is why three passwords in the database have same hash value. Was it generated and updated outside this program?

Comment: Ok i understand but when i register using default Strength of 10 and still try to login i get error                                                                                                                             `$2a$10$sROG0nq1ucs/tmoREgukBulshg0FBMYeYnK/K35f0nfkOXjYMu4Ou                    
2022-10-06 20:26:46.836  WARN 18888 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt `  or my by i do something wrong in code i have gone maytime with code but i cant find the resaon

Comment: The website you are using to generate Hash online may be the issue. Use different website

Comment: I don't think it's because of the password its somewhere in the code where we are not handling incoming passwords from the user to BCrypt and then matching, while debugging I noticed it try to match with the plain password with is entered by me(user) with BCrypt password from Database. And i don't know how to handle this or convert the input password to BCrypt because normally it's handled by spring security (If I am not wrong)